# Cross-compiled ARM executable can't open existing libpthread.so library file

Tags: pthreads, arm, cross-compiling, mysql

I'm cross-compiling programs that run on an ARM processor under a very stripped-down Linux, kernel version 2.4.26. One program uses libmysqlclient which has worked for years. However, the version I've used in the past (libmysqlclient.so.10) doesn't seem work with my new remote Mysql server (5.5.31).

I got a newer version of libmysqlclient (version 15). My program now generates a run-time error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I assume that means that the new libmysqlclient needs libpthreads. I've copied a recent ARM libpthread.so file into the /lib directory:

```
$ ls -l /lib/libpthread* 
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root       111324 Aug  6 08:46 /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           17 Aug  6 08:47 /lib/libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.7.so
```

Still get the same error. The target system is stripped down to the extent that it doesn't have ldconfig or ldd or much else. ldd run on another more capable system against the executable shows no surprises:

```
ts7500:# ldd vecsSqlLogger
libmysqlclient.so.15 => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15 (0x40026000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x401f9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x40322000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x40340000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x40379000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x40396000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x4040e000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x40000000)

ts7500:# file /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
/lib/libpthread-2.7.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.12, not stripped
```

Why am I getting this error? The library file is clearly in the expected directory. Could it be that the problem is that libpthread.so is compiled for a kernel version later than mine?

Comment: My run-time environment is really minimal - no strace, no /etc/ld.so.cache. I had checked out the ld.so man page and it looks like /lib is a default directory. My executable finds other libraries that are there at run time - libmysqlclient, for instance. Here are the relevant lines from LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS and LD_DEBUG=libs:

Comment: `253: find library=libpthread.so.0; searching
253: search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
253: search path=/lib:/usr/lib/v4l:/usr/lib (system search path)
253: trying file=/lib/libpthread.so.0
253: trying file=/usr/lib/v4l/libpthread.so.0
253: trying file=/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
...
libpthread.so.0 => not found

`

Comment: Here you go - thanks for the suggestion. This is LD_DEBUG=all, and I show the result of ls -l for the pthread lib files at the end: http://pastebin.com/zhwaM2u8

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it doesn't even parse the *libpthread.so.0*.  Can you try to make it a hard link instead of a soft link?  I was expecting that it wouldn't like the library version.  I don't know; did the *libpthread.so.0* come from the compiler directory?  It should be in `*chain-name*/sysroot/lib`.

Comment: Exactly the same with hard link. _libpthread.so.0_ came from the /lib directory of another newer ARM platform, neither with a full complement of tools. It's a later kernel version, and  _libpthread.so.0_ shows as being compiled for a later version. Could that be the problem? Here's a comparison between a lib that works (libmysqlclient) and libpthread: http://pastebin.com/Ysz4iS0b

Comment: Use the *libpthread.so.0* from the compiler if it exists.  You can not just grap a random *libpthread*; it has to be compiled for the same libraries.

Comment: That did it - thanks. I had to find a libpthread that had been compiled with the same kernel version - a little archaeology, but I found one finally.